# PasswordLess SSH

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ssh-keys

We have establish a Passwordless SSH connection between Windows Machine and Linux.

For this we have copied public key in .ssh/authorized_key in linux machine.

SSH connection was working fine and we were using "userA" for SSH.

But when password of "userA" got expired SSH connection stopped working.

As we were using keys not password why SSH connection stopped working?

Comment: Did userA change its password so its currently possible to log on using that password?

Comment: @Gerard UserA password is locked currently and not able to login.

Comment: So, try to give UserA a new, valid password.  Its account may be locked too, see if you need to unlock it.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes i will work with Admin to unlock account and get password.But my question here is i was doing SSH with account using keys not password then why SSH stopped working ?

Comment: There is no relation between a locked account and an expired password.  Passwordless SSH cannot get past a locked account.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille We have miss-typed password couple of times hence its locked.Will this cause passwordless SSH to stop working?

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it?   Am i wrong?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I got confused hence asked again.Thanks!!